# Convert Geometry from T-SQL to Postgres

Tags: postgis, postgresql-9.1, sqlgeometry

I have this column for creating a geometry from SQL Server:

```
Shape  AS ([geometry]::STGeomFromText(((('POINT('+CONVERT([varchar](20);,Longitude))+' ')+CONVERT([varchar](20),Latitude))+')',(4326))), PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
```

I need to create the column from SQL Server to Postgres:

```
CREATE EXTENSION postgis;

CREATE EXTENSION postgis_topology;
```

I also changed the STGeomFromText to ST_GeomFromText but I'm getting an error in pgAdmin:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "AS"
LINE 32:  Shape  AS ([geometry]::STGeomFromText(((('POINT('+CONVERT([...
             ^

********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near "AS"
SQL state: 42601
Character: 818
```

Did I missed something to install for postgis or the syntax needs a complete overhaul for postgres?

Comment: Unrelated, but: Postgres 9.1 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade to the current version as soon as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That syntax is completely invalid for Postgres (and not valid standard SQL either). It seems you blindly copied that definition from SQL Server

- The string concatenation operator is `||` in SQL, not `+`.
- Square brackets are invalid for identifiers in SQL.
- Postgres has no `CLUSTERED` indexes.

But most importantly: Postgres currently (Postgres 11) has no computed (generated) columns so you can't define a column as a computed on using `Shape AS <expression>`

They will be available in the upcoming version 12 (to be released in Q4/2019).

Related:

- [PostgreSQL: creating a generated column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57056037/)
- [Computed / calculated / virtual / derived columns in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8250389/)